# How to find all elements between two elements repeatedly in a list in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like

```
[item 1, abc, item 2, def, item 3, ghi, item 1, jkl, item 2]
```

I want to find all elements between 'item 1' and 'item 2', together with the start element 'item 1'.

What I want should look like:

```
[item 1, abc, item 1, jkl]
```

By the way, for 'item 1' and 'item 2', I prefer to use regular expression to match them, since it may varies in different texts, e.g., 'item 1' in some texts, but 'item1' in other texts.

Is there any way to work it out? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have formatting issues. Please format your code properly so that others find it feasible answering your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Break the process down.  Find regex patterns matching <pattern>.  Get the index of element(s) matching the pattern.  Slice the list accordingly.  What have you tried so far? Hint: `re.findall()`.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Is there a reason your desired output is `[item 1, abc, item 1, jkl]` rather than `[item 1, abc, item 2, def, item 3, ghi, item 1, jkl]` (which is closer to your description)?

Comment: I need the text between each pairs of begin (item 1) and end (item 2), including the begin. So it should be [item 1, abc, item 1, jkl].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
my_list = ['some 1', 'some', 'item 1', 'abc', 'item 2', 'def', 'item 3', 'ghi', 'item 1', 'jkl', 'item 2', 'item 3']
index_1 = [i for i, val in enumerate(my_list) if val == 'item 1']
index_2 = [i for i, val in enumerate(my_list) if val == 'item 2']
output = []
for i, j in zip(index_1, index_2):
    output.extend(my_list[i:j])
print(output)
```

**Result:**

```
['item 1', 'abc', 'item 1', 'jkl']
```

However it works only if `item  2` is followed by `item 1`.
if that's not the case some care has to be taken before the last `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Next code finds leftmost match of regex `re1` and rightmost of regex `re2` and prints this sub-range, if any `re1` not found then sub-range starts from 0-th element, if `re2` not found the ends at the end of list.

If you need to throw error when `re1` or `re2` not found then replace `[default]` with `[]` in code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/LbsMwDLv7K3SrBXhF094G7EtcH9JGabTZTqA6QPf1mZz1gfpgExRJ0dNvGcZ8WBZO0ygFhEyEL/Cb65gImo2DFdWXC6V/pj2dn8S@oo76J3Go6DLwu@X7J75b7tpghBqna/e6VV4GeUjNiS6cHVDuai8Deqxn6EcBVho462xOJG0hGxG417RtP8eY2nIerKgIA6jca812jiWg5@4W1qgaowp7HznQCdZMa9didudgh6hAK@odKesSBx8NIppgJuFcbNQPHbPWfpV9MNGvHHxWMqBZlj8)

```
import re
l = ['some 1', 'some', 'item 1', 'abc', 'item 2', 'def', 'item 3', 'ghi', 'item 1', 'jkl', 'item 2', 'item 3']
re1, re2 = r'item 1', r'item 2'
begin, end = [
    ([i for i, e in enumerate(l) if re.fullmatch(r, e)] or [default])[idx]
    for r, (default, idx) in ((re1, (0, 0)), (re2, (len(l), -1)))
]
print(l, '\n', begin, end, '\n', l[begin : end])
```

Output of code above:

```
['some 1', 'some', 'item 1', 'abc', 'item 2', 'def', 'item 3', 'ghi', 'item 1', 'jkl', 'item 2', 'item 3'] 
 2 10 
 ['item 1', 'abc', 'item 2', 'def', 'item 3', 'ghi', 'item 1', 'jkl']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, what I want is the text between each pairs of begin (item 1) and end (item 2), including the begin. It should be ['item 1', 'abc', 'item 1', 'jkl'].